# EFCore cli generate a useless migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, migration

I have a migration that create a column in a table.

```cs
public partial class AddName : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "Value 1");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Name",
            table: "MyTable");
    }
}
```

I update my database with it. And I generate a new migration.
This last should be empty but it contains an useless `AlterColumn`.

```cs
public partial class Test : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "Value 1",
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "MyTable",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldDefaultValue: "Value 1");
    }
}
```

To generate this migrations and update database, I use `dotnet-ef` cli.

I check it and I find no difference between two migrations. When I update database with `Test` migration, no changes are applied to table.
I also test to update my database to a migration prior to `AddName` and create it again. But I have same result. Second migration stay fill with `AlterColumn`.

Someone already has this strange behavior?

Comment: Have you updated your version of the [EF Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) after the first migration? It could be the cause.

Comment: Indeed first was generated with a lower version than one use for second.
I fix it to keep Snapshot generated after second migrations. So all is good now

Comment: Okie dokie. I'll add an answer for the benefit of others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by updating the [EF Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) to a newer version between generating the migrations. There can be a difference in the snapshot generated by the migrations using different versions of the Tools.